# How to program an android service which identifies my home wifi to turn on voip

Tags: android, sip, android-service, android-wifi, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

is there a simple way to program a service for android that turns the native sip client on when the phone gets connected to my wifi at home?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This may get you started:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html